MacOS command line to get/write "Description" field in files
What is the command line to retrieve and write macOS file info "Description" field?
For the command line to get "Comments" field, I use this AppleScript command:
osascript -e 'on run {f, c}' -e 'tell app "Finder" to set comment of (POSIX file f as alias) to c' -e end "grace.mov" "hello world"

The files originate on an iphone where I add comments to photos and videos. When I send these to my Mac, the only way to view them is to do a Get Info and view the "Description" field. The Comments field is empty. Ideally I would like to copy what is in the Description field to the Comments field so they are visible in List view.
I've tried the commands mdls, xattr, exiftool, sips, identify to figure out which can list the Description.
On iCloud, this field is called "Caption" (viewed under the Info for the image).

I don't see Description field when I do Get info. In which section do you see it ?

The Finder doesn't exist on iOS devices, so its comments, which are a mixture of its .DSStore file, the com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment extended attribute (a binary property list), and Spotlight kMDItemFinderComment metadata, wouldn't apply.
If they are something like macOS Photos captions, those would be Spotlight kMDItemDescription, and/or Exif Description metadata.  You can copy Spotlight's kMDItemDescription metadata, just be aware that if you are wanting to set an extended attribute via xattr, the comment synchronization between the Finder, extended attributes, and Spotlight isn't very reliable.
One approach would be to get the Spotlight metadata and then tell Finder to set its comment, for example:
set theFile to (choose file)
set caption to (do shell script "/usr/bin/mdls -name kMDItemDescription -raw " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile)
if caption is not in {"", "(null)"} then
    tell application "Finder"
        set existing to comment of theFile
        set comment of theFile to existing & return & caption -- append
        # set comment of theFile to caption -- overwrite
    end tell
else -- no value
    beep -- or whatever
end if


This script does the trick in copying what is in the Description field in a MOV or PNG to the Finder Comments area (although it seems to add a blank return character at the beginning so the comment is not visible in List view).
I notice in PNG files, the text is NOT stored inside the file (ie. I do a BeyondCompare binary and the file with and without the description is the same size and identical binary content).
Because this Description text is stored by the Mac "elsewhere", when viewed on a Windows machine the Comment field is blank (unlike .MOV file)

@SillyWonka - Correct. Finder, Spotlight, and the extended attributes are a macOS thing stored separately from the file.  For something more portable in the file itself, you would need to add Exif Description metadata via ExifTool.

Here is an alternative approach that uses applescript's Image Events to retrieve the 'description' field. Image Events is the applescript version/interface of the command line utility sips.
use scripting additions
set tagName to "description"

tell application "Finder"
    set sel to (choose file) as alias
end tell

tell application "Image Events"
    set ieSel to open sel -- opens image within Image Events
    
    try
        set tagValue to value of metadata tag tagName of ieSel
        tell application "Finder" to set comment of sel to (get comment of sel & "; " & tagValue)
    on error number -1728
        -- can't use 'dialog' with Image Events
        tell me to display notification "Can't find that tag"
    end try
end tell

NB There may be other reasons for a -1728 error
Additional:
The sips command to retrieve the 'description' is this:
sips --getProperty description filename

Modify a tag using sips like so:
sips --setProperty description "new description" filename

